# Memory error (MemoryError) when creating a boolean NumPy array (Python)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using NumPy with Python 2.6.2. I'm trying to create a small (length 3), simple boolean array. The following gives me a MemoryError, which I think it ought not to.

```
import numpy as np
cond = np.fromiter((x in [2] for x in [0, 1, 2]), dtype = np.bool)
```

The error it gives me is:

MemoryError: cannot allocate array memory

However, the following method of obtaining a list (as opposed to an ndarray) works fine (without using numpy):

```
cond = list((x in [2] for x in [0, 1, 2]))
```

Have I done anything wrong in the Numpy code? My feeling is that it ought to work.

Comment: Your first code works for me as is. Can you post the versions of Python and Numpy?

Comment: For what it's worth, I can reproduce the problem using python 2.5 and numpy 1.1, but not with anything newer.  On the older versions, it works fine if you manually specify the `count` kwarg (`count=3`, in this case). However, that defeats the purpose of using `np.fromiter` in the first place. I assmume it's a bug in numpy that's been fixed somewhere between 1.1 and 1.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem with numpy 1.1 (but not with anything newer).  Obviously, upgrading to a more recent version of numpy is your best bet.

Nonetheless, it seems to be related to using `np.bool` as the dtype when `count=-1` (the default: Read all items in the iterator, instead of a set number).

A quick workaround is just to create it as an int array and then convert it to a boolean array:

```
cond = np.fromiter((x in [2] for x in [0, 1, 2]), dtype=np.int).astype(np.bool)
```

An alternative is to convert it to a list, and then set `count` to the length of the list (or just use `np.asarray` on the list):

```
items = list((x in [2] for x in [0, 1, 2]))
cond = np.fromiter(items, dtype=np.bool, count=len(items))
```

Obviously, both of these are suboptimal, but if you can't upgrade to a more recent version of numpy, they will work.

Comment: Thank you! I did suspect it was a bug/version thing.

Answer (score 1):

You should not get any error.

With Python 2.6.5 or Python 2.7, and Numpy 1.5.0, I don't get any error.  I therefore think that updating your software could very well solve the problem that you observe.

Comment: Thanks! I can't get a new version of numpy right now so I'll just work around it.